# Does javacv projects run differently on 32 bit and 64 bit operating systems?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I'm new to JavaCV API which works as interface to access the OpenCV. I would like to know whether there are some differences on executting same project which developed using *Netbeans* (I know that there should be different jar files should be added to project other than that).

Because I develop a project using *Netbeans* and when I run that application on 32 bit machine it runs perfectly but when I try to run it on 64 bit operating system some times it doesn't give correct output.

Please can someone explain the reason for that?

Comment: I also got same sort of problem as well.

Comment: Hello. You would need to give more information to let people help you. What kind of incorrect output? Are there any exceptions? Can you reproduce it constantly (maybe some stress tests)? Can you reproduce it on 32-bit java running on a 64-bit system, or only 64-bit java?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the project would be affected by the speed of the CPU. I have had several projects where this has happened, it is usually with more graphic intensive projects. The solution would depend on the project itself. "64 bit machines are newer. 64 bit machines have wider data paths, wider registers, along with tons features not supported by the 32 bit machine (just because they are newer).